# cannot add certain images

Tags: ios, xcode, png

Every time i add an image for i get the error below. For some reason even if i rename it it still doesn't work, this problem was happening before on another project so i deleted it and started again. i have already checked for duplicate images that did get rid of the error however once i built the project the the picture was blank and i get a message saying

`2013-11-07 16:45:28.613 Chiswick W4[1812:60b] Could not load the "1frivoli.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "Studentathome.Chiswick-W4"`

need some help urgently!!

Also i would like to add i can take a screen shot of that image and input it however i will have to do this is a worst case scenario i just want to know why my images don't work.

thank you

[image]

Comment: I have occasionally run into a similar issue with png image files created from psd files using Photoshop. The fix was to go back to Photoshop and regenerate the png file (File -> Save for Web...).

Comment: @avi if you found your solution then post here, it will help to others

Comment: Do not post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Often you can try to open the file with Preview, and if it opens resave it as a different file, and use the saved file in your project. It handles more png variations than iOS but usually writes files that can be read. Photoshop is just one of many sources that can create pngs unreadable by ios.